# Any way to add something similar to Olark or Zopim

Tags: 7

Olark and Zopim are live chat services. Is there any module to add this feature to a Drupal site? I took a look to 'chat room' module but it is not what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a free Drupal service to do this.
Olark has a [Drupal guide](http://www.olark.com/tutorials/drupal.html) to get it working on your site. There is also the [Olark Chat](http://drupal.org/project/olark) module. I know that [VPS.NET](http://vps.net/) and [Lullabot](http://www.lullabot.com/) are both using Olark.

Comment: ok, I see.Then not a free option for drupal. Olark looks really good and Zopim does too. But I can´t afford to pay their prices.

Comment: From memory zopim is free for 1 user. Could try http://www.livezilla.net/home/en/. Used this in the past before we got free chat with http://www.islonline.com/isl-light/

Comment: I´ll go with Zopim using its Lite plan. As you said it's free for one user.

Answer (score 0):

Many of us are looking for a reliable livechat for Drupal. There is no secret how to choose one of them.

First of all take a look at [this list](http://www.drupaldriven.com/qa/there-drupal-module-enables-live-chat-drupal-site) and find the solution for yourself. Then, find reviews of choosen chat and make a correct decision.